# Does changing the word order in these sentences alter the meaning?

Tags: meaning, grammar, sentence

1. Impressions are often made better by deeds than by words or money.
2. Impressions made by deeds are often better than by money or words.

Do you think these two sentences can be seen the same grammatically and in meanings?

Comment: These sentences both make sense, but the more commonly accepted phrase is **actions speak louder than words**. I would use this proverb  instead of your sentences as they seem slightly convoluted to my ear.

Comment: Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified.

Comment: It's not really clear what the question here is (I've altered the title to avoid out-and-out proofreading). However, your comment indicates that one is right and the other wrong: so it is proof-reading. If it isn't simply "which is right", please edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: One issue is the collocation of *made better* in your first example: to make something better means to improve it; that is not the intended reading, which makes the first example somewhat worse.

Answer (score 1):

The sentences you use here both make sense and demonstrate the flexibility of English; in truth, there is no solid answer.

A quick Google search for `Impressions are often made better by deeds than by words` returns "*About 3,590,000 results*" while `Impressions made by deeds are often better than by words.` returns "*About 24,400,000 results*".
On the other hand, I would opt for sentence one as it sounds better.

Despite that, as I mentioned in a comment, the more commonly accepted phrase is the [proverb](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/proverb) **actions speak louder than words**'.

[The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Actions+speak+louder+than+words) defines the phrase as the following:

> What you do is more significant than what you say.

For example:

> *You keep saying that you'll do your fair share of the housework. Remember that actions speak louder than words.*

To improve your English try to use proverbs as they make it seem more fluent.